# Dynamically rendering an image on Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to dynamically render an image in my shiny app based on the value selected by the user in the dropdown option. For each name selected by a user the name will have an associated global_id. I want to use this global_id to find an image with the matching global_id as a name and then show the image

this is a sample of my data (boxing)

```
  name     division      sex      global_id
   ab        small        male        901
   bc        middle       male        999
   cd        big          male        002
   def       small        male        123
   dgh       small        male        284
   fgh       middle       male        990
```

the images are in my www file in the same directory.

This is what I have tried

```
        dropdownButton(
          inputId = 'dropdownA',
          label='control',
          icon = icon("user",lib="glyphicon"),
          status='primary',
          circle=TRUE
        ),
        selectInput("dropdown","Boxer A",
                    choices = unique(boxing$division)),
        uiOutput("Names"),
        imageOutput("boxerA")


server <- function(input,output){
   output$boxerA <- renderImage({
       outimage <- tempfile(fileext = '.jpg')})
```

This returns the error message:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

in the area where the picture is supposed to appear on my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the answer already given, you could also render an image using uiOutput and renderUI.

So uiOutput to generate said image and renderUI to take in the input from the user selection and generate the picture you would like to show

An example of this would be:

```
#replace this
imageOutput("boxerA")
#with this
uiOutput('Picture')
#then add this to server
renderUI({tags$img(src = *picfilename*)})
```

Answer (score 0):

To integrate an image, you should return inside the `renderImage` a list object with the path to your image as `src`

```r
output$plop <- renderImage({
  list(src ="path/to/image")
})
```

```r
imageOutput("plop")
```

Note that **renderImage** has a `deleteFile` argument that means that the image is deleted once rendered.

Two ways to bypass that:

- use `deleteFile =  TRUE`
- copy and paste your image to a temp file, as in https://github.com/ThinkR-open/shinipsum/blob/master/R/Image.R